# Get active facebook access token in android

Tags: android, facebook, access-token

When facebook login is success I want accesstoken something like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NXCh.png as shown in picture. But I am getting this 
`accesstoken : {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_birthday, public_profile, contact_email, user_friends, email]}`

I tried like this

```
btnFacebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code

            Log.i(TAG,"accesstoken : "+loginResult.getAccessToken());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I dont know how to get the accesstoken that serverside programmer wanted from android side. I am so stuck with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an AccessTokenTracker listener in your activity like this:

```
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

        }
    };
```

Then in your registerCallback `onSuccess()` you can get your access token like this

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken();
```

Comment: Your welcome. Vote it up if it solved your problem ;-)

Comment: Still not getting Access Token. When I debug I'm getting **{Request:  accessToken: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, user_friends, email]}, graphPath: me, graphObject: null, httpMethod: GET, parameters: Bundle[{}]}**

Using Facebook SDK Version: 4.22.0 @abeikverdi